# Is the Operating Income or Loss equivalent to Total Revenues for wealthier companies?

Tags: investing, financial-literacy, starting-out-investing, income, yahoo-finance

I have noticed on yahoo finance that some companies like [this one](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/BRK.AX/financials?p=BRK.AX) don't have *total revenues* in their financial table but rather an *Operating Income or Loss* and a *Net Income*. Is it the same ? Can I use it for [Graham second rule for filtering large enough companies](https://youtu.be/npoyc_X5zO8?t=249) (that have sales greater than $700m)?

I'm young and new to financial analysis and investing. Maybe I'm wrong and I shouldn't even have used Total Revenues from yahoo financial sheet. Let me know if I do mistakes, I'm eager to learn.

Comment: You picked an odd example - that company looks like it is near bankruptcy and is losing money by the day. If you are new to investing, please please please don't buy penny stocks; that is more like gambling than investing.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon Yes, that's why I tried to sort them out. Should I only focus on pages where they have an actual `Total Revenues` ?

Answer (score 2):

NO -- [Operating Income is NOT the same as Revenue](https://www.investopedia.com/ask/answers/122714/what-difference-between-operating-income-and-revenue.asp).

This company is a weird example - it looks like it's going BK. But, an example:

Revenue = $100 --- Payroll = ($30) --- Office Rent = ($20) --- Operating Income => $50

Answer (score 1):

> Operating Income or Loss and a Net Income. Is it the same ?

No - companies can have revenue and expenses that are not based on the actual operations of the company - interest paid on debt is a common example.  Net Income starts with the Operating Income (Operating Revenue minus Operating Expenses), and adds/subtracts any non-operating revenue/expenses.

For your particular example, this looks like incomplete data, where operating revenue and expenses aren't broken out. Only a net total is shown. If you look at the [financial statements](http://brookside-energy.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/BRK-Annual-Report-2018.-Final.pdf) on their [web site](http://brookside-energy.com.au/asx-releases/) you will see actual revenue listed.